# boost::enable_if on member function, overload return type

Tags: c++, templates, boost, template-meta-programming, c++03

I want to be able to use `boost::enable_if` to turn off/on some methods.

For integral types I want to return `TypeToReturn` from `operator()`
For other types I want to return `const TypeToReturn&`

This is my attempt:

```
template<typename T>
struct Holder{
    typedef T type;
};


template<typename First,
         typename TypeToReturn = typename Holder<First>::type>

struct SuperClass{

    typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<TypeToReturn> >::type 
    operator()(int& someParameterNotImportant) const
    {
        // stuff
    }

    const typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_integral<TypeToReturn> >::type&
    operator()(int& someParameterNotImportant) const
    {
        // stuff
    }
};
```

I am getting errors that these functions cannot be overloaded etc.

I am not even sure if this attempt is step in good direction.

EDIT: After first suggestion I am adding code after correction,
still gives problem that "const typename boost::disable_if..... cannot be overloaded"

```
template<typename T>
struct Holder{
    typedef T type;
};


template<typename First,
         typename TypeToReturn = typename Holder<First>::type>

struct SuperClass{

    typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<TypeToReturn>, TypeToReturn >::type 
    operator()(int& someParameterNotImportant) const
    {
        // stuff
    }

    const typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_integral<TypeToReturn>, TypeToReturn >::type&
    operator()(int& someParameterNotImportant) const
    {
        // stuff
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

SFINAE applies to template methods. your are not.

In C++11, we can have default template for function to handle that:

```cpp
template<typename First,
         typename TypeToReturn = typename Holder<First>::type>
struct SuperClass
{
    template <typename T = TypeToReturn>
    typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<T>, T>::type 
    operator()(int& someParameterNotImportant) const
    {
        // stuff
    }

    template <typename T = TypeToReturn>
    const typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_integral<T>, T>::type&
    operator()(int& someParameterNotImportant) const
    {
        // stuff
    }
};
```

C++17 would allow simpler syntax with `if constexpr`,

and C++20 would allows `requires` to discard the method thanks to traits.

In C++03, I would suggest tag dispatching instead:

```cpp
template<typename First,
         typename TypeToReturn>
TypeToReturn helper(int& someParameterNotImportant, boost::true_type)
{
// stuff
}

template<typename First,
         typename TypeToReturn>
const TypeToReturn& helper(int& someParameterNotImportant, boost::false_type)
{
// stuff
}


template<typename First,
         typename TypeToReturn = typename Holder<First>::type>
struct SuperClass
{
    typename boost::conditional<boost::is_integral<TypeToReturn>::value,
                                TypeToReturn,
                                const TypeToReturn&>::type 
    operator()(int& someParameterNotImportant) const
    {
        return helper<First, TypeToReturn>(someParameterNotImportant,
                                           boost::is_integral<TypeToReturn>());
    }
};
```

Comment: this is probably not applicable in c++03 with this default template arguments?

Comment: @Newbie: Indeed, version restriction added.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a type to the enable_if

```
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<TypeToReturn>, TypeToReturn >::type
```

otherwise it defaults to void

And to make it working for real you need to either make operator's template functions by themselves to allow SFINAE to kick in thru this won't work for the c++03 as stated in tags.

```
template <typename Ret = TypeToReturn>
typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<Ret>,Ret >::type 
operator()(int& someParameterNotImportant) const
```

Or use dummy variable and make operators differ by the parameters instead of return value. But still keeping it template. This will work for the c++03

```
template<typename T>
    TypeToReturn operator()(T& someParameterNotImportant, typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_integral<TypeToReturn>,T >::type* = 0) const
```

You may also add check for the T being int here to issue compile time error if it isn't.

Comment: oh, thanks, but does not solve the problem with "const typename .... disable_if..... cannot be overloaded"

Comment: Have you provided TypeToReturn there as well?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/0lLydC
You can use slightly different approach to using enable/disable_if

Comment: @alexrider this will not work for int arrays?
https://godbolt.org/z/PaHGYQ  (maybe not the best)
for that case it is not "integral" so I would like to return const &

Comment: I mean when TypeToReturn will be array, so operator() should return const TypeToReturn&

Comment: `someParameterNotImportant` is `int&` in OP case. you change that too. (and using SFINAE on that parameter would disallow conversion operator for example)